# Cannot create a Visio Graphics Service in SharePoint 2016

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, visio-services

While creating the Visio Graphics service, I get the following error:

```
Sorry, something went wrong 
This Page has been modified since you opened it. You must open the page again.
```

When I look into the ULS, I see this:

```
Application error when access /_admin/VisioServiceApplications.aspx,
Error=Invalid viewstate.    Client IP: fe80::f403:4783:bee8:2e01%12   
Port: 52066   Referer: 
http://sp_app_01:9000/_admin/VisioServiceApplications.aspx?IsDlg=1   
Path: /_admin/VisioServiceApplications.aspx   User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 
(compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; .NET4.0E; .NET4.0C; 
.NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.30729)   ViewState...
```

Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

This error telling us that Visio Graphic Service is not healthy state, try this

- From Central admin > Manage Service on Server.

  - Check if Visio service is running. if yes, then stop it and start it.
  - If not started then start.
- From IIS, Please recycle the Application Pool of Visio Graphic Service.

Comment: Visio Service is not installed yet. I get the error above while I am creating a Visio Serice in Central Admin.

Comment: Start the Visio graphic service 1st then try to create the service application

Comment: I am having the exact issue here. I see that Visio Graphics Service is stopped but there is not button to Start it. Any idea?